# Decrypt EXE on the fly

Tags: winapi, hook, createprocess

I have an `XXX.EXE` which is a result of applying `AES` to original `.EXE`
I have a host process, which calls CreateProcess on the `XXX.EXE`
There is a decryption method in host process allowing to decrypt any block of the `.EXE` (which is simple because host process knows the AES key).

I want to find a simple way to execute the decrypted `.EXE` and if possible to avoid storing the entire `.EXE` in memory.

I tried to install hook for ReadFile to make it decrypt on the fly when called by `CreateProcess`, but this does not work because CreateProcess also calls `CreateFileMapping`, which probably reads file using kernel-mode functions, so I am stuck.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What about hooking `WriteProcessMemory`? I assume it uses CreateProcess to start a suspended "victim" before it overwrites it and then resumes it. [This article](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/01/windows-dll-injection-basics.html) goes into quite a bit of detail, including functions that  might be worth hooking.

Comment: You are of course aware that this means that the pages in your program cannot be discarded and re-read from disk again (as is normally the case with an executable that is simply memory-mapped read-only)? So this will only work as long as there is sufficient backing on the page file. Now let's hope none of your users ever disable the page file.

Comment: Damon, so you mean that every page of decrypted EXE code needs to be present either in page file or in EXE file on disk... So in case page file is disabled, the entire decrypted EXE needs to be present on disk...
Isn't there a way to hook page fault event when page is read from disk to memory, to decrypt it on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is essentially run a [packed executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression) in order to obfuscate what is running.  The packers will allow you to run the executable as normal and will have a small piece of unobfuscated/unencrypted code that will unpack the rest of your binary.

Some packers will not need to unpack the entire binary in one go, while others will.  However, this is a technique commonly used by malware to make reverse engineering more difficult.  This in turn causes anti-virus companies to mark packed software as malware.

It is possible to write your own executable [loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29) to decrypt the rest of the executable and load imported functions, etc.  [This article](http://www.cultdeadcow.com/tools/pewrap.html) explains the steps involved in the Windows loader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am trying to do is encryption rather than obfuscation, because only a "host" process knows decryption key. So I am not sure that self-unpacking will help... Anyway thanks...
And the link to the article does not work...

Comment: It would be helpful to know what threat you're trying to protect against.  Some packers do encrypt the executable data, but ultimately it is only obfuscated.  This is because when it comes to running the program the code must be decrypted (at least in part).  Someone who is reverse engineering the program can just wait for that to happen and then dump the process memory to disk and get the unencrypted executable.